# Django prefetch_related is taking to much runtime

Tags: django, database

I need to list all my devices. To do this I use a prefetch related to reduce the amount of queries. But one of them is consuming to much time.. I wonder if it can't go better.

I will start with the model construction: I want a list of devices. This is the device model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_active_gateway(self):
        from backend.gateways.models import Gateway

        all_gatewaydevices = self.gatewaydevices.all()
        for gd in all_gatewaydevices:
            if not gd.end_date:
                return gd.gateway
        return None
```

In the real code the model is larger, but that code is irrelevant. As you can see, a device has some gatewaydevices (which is a model between gateway and device)

The `gatewaydevice` model looks like:

```
class GatewayDevice(models.Model):
    gateway = models.ForeignKey(
        Gateway, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="devices"
    )
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="gatewaydevices"
    )
```

So in my list of devices, I want for every device, the linked gateway.

This is my view:

```
class AdminDeviceView(GenericAPIView):
    def get_permissions(self):
        return IsAuthenticated()

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return AdminDeviceInfoSerializer

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={
            200: openapi.Response(
                _("Successfully fetched all data from devices."),
                AdminDeviceInfoSerializer,
            )
        }
    )
    def get(self, request):
        devices = (
            Device.objects.prefetch_related(
                "gatewaydevices__gateway",
            )
            .all()
        )

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer = serializer_class(devices, many=True)
        devices_data = serializer.data

        return Response(
            {"total": devices.count(), "items": devices_data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

This is the part of the serializer that is important:

```
@staticmethod
def get_gateway(device):
    gateway = device.get_active_gateway()
    return GatewaySimpleSerializer(gateway).data if gateway else None
```

Can this get any faster/more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

`get_active_gateway` is very inefficient - it check each object separately. And when called in `get_gateway` - it does not utilize prefetch bonuses.

---

You can filter and get only valid `Gateway` objects directly in prefetch.

Also using `to_attr` to map result to same field name as in serializer.

(*not tested)

```
class AdminDeviceView(GenericAPIView):
    # ...
    def get(self, request):
    # ...
        devices = Device.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "gatewaydevices",
                queryset=Gateway.objects.filter(
                    devices__end_date__isnull=True
                ).order_by().distinct(), # distinct in case there are many
                to_attr="gateway",
            )
        )
    # ...


class AdminDeviceInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gateway = GatewaySimpleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # ...
```

Comment: I get a "app_1            | TypeError: prefetch_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
" any idea why?

Comment: Added missing closing bracket for Prefetch(). `queryset` is in `Prefetch` object, which goes to `prefetch_related`

Comment: Thanks, the query seems to stay the same. I had to chance gatewaydevices__end_date__isnull  to devices__end_date__isnull in your solution because devices is the lookup field in GatewayDevice. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it should be accessor name to GatewayDevice from Gateway. The idea is to include only filtered / active gateways in prefetch, so no need to filter later (and thus making new queries outside prefetch) and using same attr name for queryset as field name in serializer to make it use gateways from prefetched queryset, not from separate method making separate queries.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. This query keeps taking so long.. I think it's from "gatewaydevices__gateway" : 

SELECT ••• FROM "gateways_gatewaydevice" WHERE ("gateways_gatewaydevice"."end_date" IS NULL AND "gateways_gatewaydevice"."device_id" IN (1,2,3,4,5,6...)

Comment: Please check update to answer: it appears lookup in Prefetch should be just to gatewaydevices, not futher to gateway: `Prefetch("gatewaydevices")`, also added empty `order_by()` before distinct to prevent unnecessary sorting; also `gateway` result attribute in queryset will be a list, so `many=True` in serializer.

Comment: What is the approximate count of devices / gateways in database to estimate speed?

Comment: Thanks, very strange. When I add the prefetch now I get a "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'device' into field.". When I debug it, it doesn't occur..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213325/discussion-between-oleg-russkin-and-codinginquarantine).